# Ryan Dahl's Node Chat

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can someone explain in details the Node Chat written by Ryan Dahl. It used the core Node.js methods without using the Socket.io. I've searched a lot for the documented version. I couldn't find one. Can someone please help me with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even I've been looking for such a solution. The best one out there is https://github.com/neerajdotname/node-chat-in-steps

This guy explains it in steps. I found it very helpful. At least to a very good extent.